# Radix 2 square root

Tags: arithmetic

I am trying to understand the radix-2 square root shown in Chapter 6 of Digital Arithmetic(Miloš D.ErcegovacTomásLang). I am missing something in the computation of F[j]. I am attaching the formula used for F[j] and the example given in the textbook(for x = 0.10110111). Please help me in understanding how F[j] is computed.
[F[j] formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpZEc.png)
[Square root example for x = 0.10110111](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mqpC.png)

Comment: What do  $w,\;2w[1]^+$ denote?

Comment: What is the method of computation? How you move from one level to the next?